# Maximum search factor and average search factor java

Tags: java, hash

I need to find the max search factor and average search factor in a table.

I have statistics of what it is supposed to be and my statistics keeps coming out to be greater than that given.

```
public void printStatistics() {
    int numFilledLocations = 0;
    for (Hash hash: hashTable) {
        if (!hash.val.isEmpty()) {
            numFilledLocations++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Load Factor: " + ((float) numFilledLocations) / (float) tableSize);
    int maxLength = 0;
    int totalLengths = 0;
    for (Hash hash: hashTable) {
        int length = 1;
        Hash nextHash = hash;
        while (nextHash.next != -1) {
            length++;
            nextHash = hashTable[nextHash.next];
        }
        if (length > maxLength) {
            maxLength = length;
        }
        totalLengths += length;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of length linked list: " + totalLengths);
    System.out.println("Maximum Search Factor: " + maxLength);
    System.out.println("Average Search Factor: " + ((float) totalLengths / (float) tableSize));
}
```

Comment: sorry I was not more specific I do not understand what max search factor or total search factor is

Comment: What is a search factor?

Comment: I imagine that you are trying to measure hash collision rigth?